# Predefined cpu target macro for Cortex-M0+

Tags: c, embedded, arm, cortex-m

I am currently using predefined cpu target macros to make software run on multiple cpu targets.

```
#ifdef __TARGET_CPU_CORTEX_M0
    [do something here]
#elif __TARGET_CPU_CORTEX_M3
    [do something here]
#else
    #error Unsupported compiler platform
#endif
```

Example:

This works for Cortex-M0 and Cortex-M3, but I can't figure out what macro to use for Cortex-M0+. Does anyone know which macro I can use?
I use the armcc compiler.

Comment: I use GCC and for that compiler you need to supply the CPU type to the compiler. This can be done using global defines (e.g. __TARGET_CPU_CORTEX_M3) which you then can use in your code also. I guess that the ARM compiler works in a similar manner. You probably need to supply the compiler with an additional/different CPU 'flag'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @wlamers for your reply. The ARM compiler creates these defines from the compiler option `--cpu Cortex-M0+`. This does work for parameter Cortex-M0 and Cortex-M3, but Cortex-M0+ does not work. According to the documentation there should be a predefined macro for this platform, but I just can't figure out which one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [documented](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0375e/pge1397113341080.html), albeit rather obliquely. The relevant macro name is derived from the command-line option, thus `--cpu=Cortex-M0plus` defines `__TARGET_CPU_CORTEX_M0PLUS`.

Annoyingly, whilst it doesn't show up in the `--cpu=list` output, the compiler (I tried armcc version 5.04) *does* also recognise the option `--cpu=Cortex-M0+`, for which it defines the macro `__TARGET_CPU_CORTEX_M0_`

In general, invoking `armcc --cpu=xx --list_macros /dev/null` will show what macros are defined for cpu option *xx* (or an error if it isn't supported).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This however does not work in my situation. I use the compiler option `--cpu Cortex-M0+`, so according to the documentation the define would be `__TARGET_CPU_CORTEX_M0+`; this, however, is not a valid define. I have tried `__TARGET_CPU_CORTEX_M0PLUS`, `__TARGET_CPU_CORTEX_M0_PLUS`, `__TARGET_CPU_CORTEX_M0P` and `__TARGET_CPU_CORTEX_M0_P`, but with no success.

Comment: @NilsdeJong Are you sure your compiler option is correct? Answer said `--cpu=Cortex-M0plus`, not `--cpu Cortex-M0+`.

Comment: I use Keil uVision, which adds the compiler option `--cpu Cortex-M0+` for me based on the chosen target. I use the NXP LPC1114FHN33/301 microcontroller and their documentation says it is based on Cortex-M0 (instead of Cortex-M0+). The compiler option may be invalid; I have contacted ARM support for this issue...

Comment: The device I use is apparently twice in the device list: once as _LPC1114FHN33/301_ with the wrong compiler option `--cpu Cortex-M0+` and once as _LPC1114/301_ with compiler option `--cpu Cortex-M0`. Using the last one fixed my problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!